# Mapping to complex objects with restkit

Tags: json, restkit-0.20, object-object-mapping

I  am trying to map a complex json object to my objects

my json contains a property that is a true or false value:

```
object {

rootProp2 = 1; <== fails to get mapped (this is a BOOL object)

} to object result: (null), (null),(null),(null) with object mapping (null)
```

how do i tell restkit to map  rootProp2 to a BOOL value

it stays as 0, even though server returns "true" for this value

why arent my BOOL values mapped correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

This is very sad i had to debug this for a few hours
but the reason for the problem that my json came with property name rootProop2
and my mapping had rootProp2 -> 1 missing letter and all goes kaput!

Comment: In this case, if you turn on trace logging and search for the key I think you should have found a log saying that the source key didn't exist. `Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath rootProp2`. You still need to spot the typo after that though...